# Why does trunc(1) output as 0?

Tags: c++, double, decimal-point, truncation

Can someone explain me why in c++ happens such a thing:

```
double tmp;
...                    // I do some operations with tmp 
                       // after which it has to be equal to one
cout << tmp;           // prints 1
cout << trunc(tmp);    // prints 0
cout << trunc(tmp*10); // prints 9
```

I am using this for separation part right of decimal part from the number for example if i have: 5.010 ... i want to have 0.010 .. so I am using:

```
double remainder = tmp - trunc(tmp);
```

---

I am posting the whole code....the suggestion with floor does not worked

```
short getPrecision(double num, short maxPrecision) {

  // Retrieve only part right of decimal point
  double tmp  = fabs(num - trunc(num));
  double remainder = tmp;

  // Count number of decimal places
  int c = 0;
  while (remainder > 0 && c < maxPrecision) {
    tmp *= 10;
    remainder = tmp - trunc(tmp);
    c++;
  }
  return c;
}
```

When I run this function for example with 5.1 the remanider is 0 instead of 1

Comment: Can you show us the operations? Because as pointed out in Armen's answer points out, sometimes double operations are not exact.

Comment: Try setting the precision to 17 before outputting the values.  `<<` rounds (to 6 digits precision by default).  It's not too surprising that truncating and rounding give different results.

Comment: or you could try outputting tmp - 1. It looks to me like tmp does not have to be 1 at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some calculations it has to be one? Well, it could as well be `0.99999999999999999`. Floating point operations are not precise, you should always take that into account.

Comment: Well, 0.(9) is exactly equal to 1 btw ;P

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Yes, but only if there is an infinite number of nines. But in computers, everything is finite :P

Answer (score 1):

Please see picture at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc. The chart there explains the inconsistency with `trunc`ing 1. Probably the same applies to 10 as well

This should help you achieving what you need:

```
double remainder = tmp - floor(tmp);
```